# Method in WebApi controller not being matched with appropriate AJAX call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

My Controller code:

```
    public List<ContactDTO> GetAllContacts()
    {
        return repository.GetAllContacts().ToList();
    }

    public ContactDTO GetContact(int contactId)
    {
        return repository.GetContact(contactId);
    }
```

And my ajax call:

```
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:54185/contacts/details/1",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
                    callback();
                },
            });
```

My ajax call to get all contacts works properly:

```
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:54185/contacts",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (result) {
                    // result is ok
                }
            });
```

I have edited both `RouteConfig` and `WebApiConfig` files, tho I'm not sure I did everything right.

```
//RouteConfig:
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Details",
                url: "contacts/details/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

And WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "contactDetails",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/details/{id}");
        }
```

So I'm not sure what I'm missing / have done wrong. With this configuration, first ajax call always falls into `GetAllContacts()` method

Comment: Try moving your 2nd Web API route above the first one?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'd do best not to confuse your routing schemes if you're using both MVC and API side by side.  And I'm not sure how GetAllContacts would work in this case, either apply a Route attribute like the previous answerer said or rename your method.

I prefer to keep my API's in a specific taxonomy:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { 
                    controller = "DefaultApi", 
                    id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

So in your case, keep your controller and keep your action.  Maybe decorate it with `[HttpGet]` for good measure:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<ContactDTO> AllContacts()
{
    return repository.GetAllContacts().ToList();
}
```

And if you are rendering your script in a .CSHTML file you can let Web API render the right path for you:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = false, controller = "Contacts", action = "AllContacts" }))",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (result) {
        // result is ok
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Atribute Routing for better understanding
You need to give full